# Directory of dereferenced symbolic link?

Tags: linux, unix, symbolic-link

In shell script, how can I dereference a symbolic link and get the directory of the file it links to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dereference symbolic links with GNU `readlink` through:

> `readlink -f /path/to/symlink`

The directory is easy to get through `dirname`:

> `dirname $(greadlink -f /path/to/symlink)`

Note that BSD `readlink` (i.e. the one that comes with OS X) does not support this `-f` option, but installing `coreutils` through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) will provide you with `greadlink`.

---

A cross-platform solution with Python:

```
python -c 'import os;print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("***/path/to/symlink***"))'
```